# How can I copy *everything* from one phone to another?

Tags: settings, lock-screens, file-transfer, launcher, data-transfer

I have a Galaxy S7. I bought a Galaxy S8. I prefer answers that are more general, but I will accept answers specific to copying the experience between these two phones.

I have tried a few options to "copy" everything, including Samsung Backup, Google Backup, and Smart Switch. However, some things were not copied over:

- Accounts. I have to log-in to Google, Facebook, LinkedIn, WhatsApp, Splitwise, etc.
- TouchWiz "Always On" screen configuration (especially the appearance of the clock).
- TouchWiz screen resolution and font size.
- Homescreen. The background transferred, but the app icon layout and widgets did not.
- App settings. The installed apps transferred, but their settings did not. It's like a fresh installation of every app.
- Ringtones. I installed and chose custom sounds for notifications and calls.

There are probably other things missing that I just haven't discovered yet. I know from long experience that text messages do not transfer, so I'm in the habit of using SMS Backup and Restore.

Some of these things might not be transferable by any means (I can see this being true for accounts, and probably my authenticators), but I suspect I am just missing "the right answer" for others.

Comment: I don't think you can copy everything. Google and other accounts you have to add manually. Backup may copy files, but the TouchWiz things won't be copied. Apps cannot be transferred with settings, nor can ringtone settings be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer all your files from one Samsung to another all you need is Smart Switch. Download it from Samsung or Google Play. After download, install, get the necessary cable then you good to go. By the way all the instructions you need is on the app itself. Enjoy!

Comment: I already tried that (and mentioned it in my original question). It doesn't copy everything.

Comment: For example account settings (cloud, email, calendars) doesn't sync. And that's a PITA